# SSRS duplicate execution for single SQL Server Agent job

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I had this weird issue after migrating the reporting server database to a new server.

The migration was pretty smooth, but after I started the reporting service in the new server, users will receive the same report subscription emails every 40-50 seconds.

For now I have removed the SMTP settings, so that the subscriptions will keep running, just no emails will be sent.

---

I have done the following:

1. Check the history of SQL Server Agent job. It looks ok, the job was ran daily at 8am.
2. Then I query the [ExecutionLog3] view, I can see the subscription has been executed multiple times.

---

So my question is: if the SQL Server Agent job didn't generate those reports, what else is generating those reports and executing those subscriptions?

Thanks in advance!

---

20150506: I made a screenshot to explain the problem:

[image]

Comment: Try to look at table `ReportServer.dbo.Event`. In normal it must be empty. If the table will have records, it can mean that stored procedure `DeleteEvent` was damaged during migration.

Comment: The original report has one active subscription and schedule, which is run daily at 8am. I want to do the same in the new server.

Comment: I have checked the Event and Notification tables, they are empty, and I believe those records are inserted by SQL Server Agent. I have checked SQL Server Agent job history, it only ran at 8am each day, which matches the subscription and schedule. That's why I don't understand where those execution emails came from. Thx

Comment: I added a screenshot to explain the issue. It's a bit too small here, you can open it in a new tab: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zkUe2.jpg, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How are you executing the ssrs reports from Agent job?

Check your report in report manager URL and go to **Manage>Subscriptions**. Check if any active subscriptions are available there for this report.

Comment: Hi please see the comment above. The report has subscription but the execution doesn't match the subscription and schedule. Thx